# Show that an ordinal is a limit ordinal if and only if it is $\omega\cdot\beta$ for some $\beta$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Show that an ordinal is a limit ordinal if and only if it is $\omega\cdot\beta$ for some $\beta$.

To show the first implication, I was trying to use transfinite induction on beta to show that $\omega\cdot\beta$ is always limit, but I got a little stuck with the induction step.

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $\omega(\beta+1)=\omega\cdot\beta+\omega$. In limit cases it's even simpler because the multiplication of two limit ordinals cannot produce a successor ordinal.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Use [Cantor Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_normal_form#Cantor_normal_form) and the fact that $\alpha\cdot(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\cdot\beta+\alpha\cdot\gamma$ for any ordinals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. With this you can prove the equivalence

**Edit:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Let us prove by induction on $\alpha$ that if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, it has the prescribed form. There are two cases:

- There is some $\gamma<\alpha$ such that there are no limit ordinals between $\gamma$ and $\alpha$. Let $\gamma_0$ be the greatest limit ordinal with $\gamma$ with $\gamma<\alpha$; which clearly exists in this case. We have that $\gamma_0+\omega$ is the least limit ordinal greater than $\gamma_0$, but so is $\alpha$, hence $\alpha=\gamma_0+\omega$. By the inductive hypothesis, $\gamma_0=\omega\cdot\beta'$ for some $\beta'$, thus $\alpha=\gamma_0+\omega=\omega\cdot(\beta'+1).$
- For any $\gamma<\alpha$ there always exist limit ordinals between $\gamma$ and $\alpha$. In this case we get that $\alpha=\sup\{\gamma<\alpha:\gamma$ is a limit ordinal$\}$. Let $\beta=\sup\{\gamma:\omega\cdot\gamma<\alpha\}$, then by the inductive hypothesis we obtain $\alpha=\lim_{\gamma\to\beta}\omega\cdot\gamma=\omega\cdot\beta.$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Just as in Asaf's Answer.

Comment: How does $\gamma_0$ exist

Comment: I think the sentence "Let $\gamma_0$ be the greatest limit ordinal with $\gamma$ with $\gamma<\alpha$" has a typo. What should it say? Also, why is $\gamma_0+\omega$ the least limit ordinal greater than $\gamma_0$?

Comment: I don't get the second dot point. If  $\alpha$ is $\omega \cdot\ 3$ and $\gamma$ is $\omega$ then there are limit ordinals between $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ and $\{ \gamma \lt \alpha : \gamma $ is an ordinal $\}$ is $\{\omega, \omega \cdot 2 \}$. But the Sup of this set is not $\omega \cdot 3$